# How to fix "This relative module was not found: * ./src/main.js in multi..." error when trying to npm run serve

Tags: vue.js, webpack-dev-server

When trying to run the application with npm run serve (on iOS), I am getting the following error:

This relative module was not found:

- ./src/main.js in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://10.0.0.5:8081/sockjs-node ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

Please bear with me, I am new to this.

I have tried a bunch of random stuff like checking for misspelling issues, reinstalling webpack, updating node, and nothing. I have no clue of what this error is about so I am not sure where to look at.

The main.js file looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store/store'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import * as VueGoogleMaps from "vue2-google-maps"
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
    load: {
        key: "AIzaSyCGiy39IZbj8oxvO4HHqSVjP5RmLSHl7mY",
        libraries: "places" // necessary for places input
    }
});

Vue.use(VeeValidate);
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    beforeCreate() {
        this.$store.commit('initialiseStore');
        this.$store.dispatch('commons/initialize');
    },
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

I expect the live web server to display, but I am getting this compilation error and it is failing.

Comment: Might be a silly question but is `main.js` in the `src` directory? Did you create the project with Vue CLI?

Comment: Yes it is in the src directory, and this project was created by someone else and I downloaded the repository, the project was created with Vue CLU, but not by me.

Answer (score 6):

I faced a similar issue after and spent hours searching.

The issue occurred in my project when I tried to install vuetify using command `vue add vuetify`. Apparently, the in automatically changes the app entry property in webpack.config automatically.

**You can either change the filename itself to main.js or change the webpack config through vue.config.js** (by reading the vue cli documentation regararding webpack config).

You can check your webpack.config by using the command `vue inspect`.

```js
 ],
 entry: {
   app: [
    './src/main.js'
   ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, this worked for me but not sure you have the same issue. I found this in one of my webpack configuration files (usually named like `webpack.dev.conf.js`):

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  include: [
    resolve('src'), 
    resolve('test'), 
    resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')
  ]
},
```

I removed `resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')` and it fixed that issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I ran across this recently after installing a new module to a Vue project. The problem went away when I updated all my other modules, too.